# Cookies not working properly in PHP to redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I seem to have an issue with my code. It doesn't redirect if cookies are not there, and it doesn't include my header.php if the cookie is there.   I made a test cookie script and I can confirm if the cookie is/or not present.

CODE:

```
//checks cookies to make sure they are logged in 
    if(isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
$username = $_COOKIE["user"]; 
$pass = $_COOKIE["password"];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$username'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );

//if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page 
if ($pass != $info['password']) 
    {
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    exit();
    } 
else //otherwise they are shown the admin area   
    { 
    include 'header.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: You placed ELSE condition in the wrong place. Should be the ELSE of first condition where you checked if cookie is set.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should use PDO or mysqli, with prepared statements.  As is, this is open to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the bunch of bad practices in your script, what I suppose is causing the malfunction is this:

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
if ($pass != $info['password'])
```

If you throw an eye at the manual this is what it says

> Return Values
>
> Returns **an array** of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE if there are no more rows...

So the code should look like

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
if ($pass != $info[0]['password'])
```

Or in php gte 5.4

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )[0];
if ($pass != $info['password'])
```

You should make sure you have `display_errors` set to `E_ALL` so you can debug simple errors like that yourself easier.

Comment: Just so I know I'm not crazy, the cookies can be spoofed, right?  If so, might mention sanitizing the input before using it in a query.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Anything that comes from the browser can be spoofed. Never trust the user

Comment: That's what I thought.  I recommended prepared statements, but this way will work too.  The OP needs to protect that query, or he/she is wide open.

Comment: @user3000199 Don't forget also, you should hash and salt your passwords.  You shouldn't be saving plain-text passwords in your database.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson that is absolutely right, but in this case the OP is asking why their redirects are not working, so that's what we answer. They don't ask about moral advice on how to protect their data. It's enough that we mention that there's something wrong with the script. Looking at this script I assume that the OP is on a fairly basic level and too much information may actually have a reverse effect on them

Answer (score 0):

Mysql functions are deprecated.  Mysqli or PDO, along with prepared statements, should be used.  Example:

```
//checks cookies to make sure they are logged in 
if(isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["password"])) {    
  $password = $_COOKIE["password"];
  /* Create the prepared statement */
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE email = ?")) {

    /*bind parameters */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_COOKIE['user']);

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Bind results to variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($dbPassword);

    /* fetch values */
    $stmt->fetch();

    if($password != $dbPassword) {
    //password didn't match, boot 'em
      header('Location:fail.php');
      exit();
    }
    //password matched, let 'em in
    else {
      header('Location:pass.php');
      exit();
    }
}
//no cookies set, boot 'em
else {
    header('Location:fail.php');
    exit();
}
```

Side note:  don't store plain text passwords.  You should be hashing the password, and adding salt.